# Issue in connection windows share smbv1 or smbv2

Tags: spring-integration

We are getting connection reset error when we are trying to connect to windows share using spring integration smb. We observed that we are getting this when we disabled smb1 in windows share.

Is there any way to know which smb version spring smb api's using or is there any way available to developer to select the version ( say smb1 or smb2 ) while making connection.

Please help

Comment: Spring Integration SMB uses `org.codelibs:jcifs` of version `1.3.18.2`: https://jcifs.samba.org/. Not sure how to help you because I'm not familiar with that low-level API.

Answer (score 0):

`Spring-integration-smb` uses JCifs which only supports SMBv1. It shouldn't be too hard to build a new Spring Integration connector which leverages [SMBJ](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj) to support SMBv2.